# Importance of normalization in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, normalization, olap, denormalization

I have developed a blackberry app(ledger management system) which makes use of SQLite for data storage.

There are several relations among the tables that i have created in my app

Following are some of the tables and their columns:

```
1. Customer Details-Name,Phone,Email
2. Bills-Name,Amount
3. Update Customer-Name
4. Update Bills-ID
```

and many other temporary tables.

While i developed the app, i never really bothered to look up whether my tables were normalized.

Now after i have completed my app, i wonder whether normalization was required or not.

Most of my queries were based on selecting the records that were inserted into Customer and bills form and then manipulating on them.

For instance, i have Customer Details table which captures all the customer data.Now once a name is recorded in the database,i do not want the same name to again be present in the table,so will this require normalization concept.

Also in a RDBMS like SQLite is normalization essential.Does it hold the same meaning as with DBMS based tables.

Also is there any difference between a OLAP and OLTP system wrt to database normalization.
If yes, what would my blackberry app be categorized into?

Appreciate a guidance if any one sound on this.

Answer (score 5):

[Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) refers to relational databases. SQLite is a [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS) like Oracle, MySQL or Postgress (I think that's what you mean by DBMS based tables), so yes, normalization applies to databases stored in SQLite. Of course you can use SQLite like a key-value store, but that doesn't seem to be your case.

Database normalization is very important, but if you design your tables carefully you usually end up with a database in [3FN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), even without trying. Going for higher FNs is probably not essential for your application.

OLAP databases usually hold denormalized data for efficiency reasons. Unless you suffer for performance problems AND you know what you are doing it is probably better don't try to do this, specially in a small application.

It seems that you are using the name of a person as key. It is probably better to assign a numeric identifier to each person and using that instead, but maybe this is no problem in your application.

Comment: Thanks for posting a response.The app i have developed is comparatively small but it makes use of a number of temporary tables inorder to hold intermediary data prior to "outstanding balance" computation that goes ahead in displaying ledger info.Infact i have used ID as primary key in customer and bill tables.So would u advise there being no need for normalization in this case?

Comment: @techie Normalization is needed for persistent data. If you are creating intermediate tables as help in a computation and discarding them later I would say you don't need normalization there. Do you really need these intermediate tables? Maybe you can use an SQL query instead? (Note that I don't have any accounting knowledge)

Comment: Data is persistent in some tables like Customer details and Bills.But i am fetching some records from these tables and manipulating them in other temp tables(yes intermediary tables were necessary in my case).So you would still suggest there to be no need for normalization right?

Comment: For persistent tables you need normalization, but it is likely that the tables are already normalized, even if you don't know it. Can you check it? For transient tables you don't need normalization.

Comment: "For instance, i have Customer Details table which captures all the customer data.Now once a name is recorded in the database,i do not want the same name to again be present in the table,so will this require normalization concept."please answer this part, it should make things clear for me.

Comment: If this is an exam question you are going to fail hard. Well yes, avoiding duplicate rows is a subset of 1st normal form, but any table with a primary key does this, no?

Answer (score 3):

Normalization is required if you want to avoid the problem of duplicate rows inserted in your customer table. To what extent is up to you. You can learn some good things by reading about what [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is and why it is used.

What you don´t want in a database is [data redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy) (unless it is planned for, for reasons concerning efficiency). Redundancy can cause inconsistency, what you want is data consistency . In your case you seem to have a quite small database so you wont need any redundancy.

Here is an example of how i would have done.

```
Customer:   custId(PK), custName,
Bills:      billId(PK), custId(FK), amount, timesStamp
CustPhone:  custId(PK)FK), type(PK), number
CustMail:   custId(PK)(FK), type(PK), mail
```

To get for example all bills from a customer it would look something like this.

```
SELECT Customer.custId, Bills.billId, Bills.amount, Bills.timeStamp Customer.custName
FROM Bills
JOIN Customer
ON Customer.custId = Bills.custId;
```

That would give you unique bills connected to a unique customer, the name of the customers doesn't matter since the primary key now is and ID and not the name.

I would recommend you to read up on normalization since it is really hard to work with if you don't understand the basic concept of it.